# retrive content from multiple url by using html dom parser

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am new to php as well as dom parser, I want to grab content of  cell from multiple url.

I can grab the table element from one url very well.

Here is my code:

```
<?php  
include('../simple_html_dom.php');  
$str = file_get_html("http://www.link1.com/");  
$html = str_get_html($str);  
 $tds = $html->find('table',1)->find('td');  
 $num = null;  
 foreach($tds as $td){   
if($td->plaintext == '123 - xyz'){  
       $next_td = $td->next_sibling();  
        $next_td1 = $next_td->next_sibling();  
        $next_td2 = $next_td1->next_sibling();  
        $next_td3 = $next_td2->next_sibling();  
        $num = $next_td3->plaintext ;   
        break;   
     }  
 }  
 echo($num);  
?>
```

the url i gave content 2 table, the other 3 url(like http://www.link2.com/) i want to give also content 2 tables
I hope it need to use array and loop over these code

plz someone help me to shot it out

---

After 4 days I found something closer to my requirement, but could not reach at end.......

```
 <?php  
    ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);  
    include('../simple_html_dom.php');  
    $links = array (  
    'https://www.link1.com',  
'https://www.link2.com',   
'https://www.link3.com', 
    'https://www.link4.com');  
    $data = array();  
    foreach ($links as $link){  
    $str = file_get_html("$link");  
    $html = str_get_html($str);  
     $tds = $html->find('table',1)->find('td');  
     $num = null;  
     foreach($tds as $td){  
         if($td->plaintext == '123 - xyz'){ 
            $next_td = $td->next_sibling();  
            $next_td1 = $next_td->next_sibling();  
            $next_td2 = $next_td1->next_sibling();  
            $next_td3 = $next_td2->next_sibling();  
            $num = $next_td3->plaintext ;    
            break;   
         }  
     }  
     //echo($num." ");  
    $data[] = $num;  
    $str->clear();  
    } 
    print_r($data);  
    ?>
```

The output is like this
Array ( [0] => 10.11 [1] => 10.07 [2] => 9.37 [3] => 11.43 )
now i want to add the element of data array. The array element is a time, I want to add these elements as time.
Just like
10.11
10.07
9.37
11.43

**41:38(I want this output)**
someone please help me